How to update subscription billing date in stripe 5.3.0.0 in ASP .NET?
I'm changing my subscription billing date to a custom date. I tried it with the "StripeSubscriptionUpdateOptions" method. But when I passed 'BillingCycleAnchor' with my date it gave an error.
Error : "When updating an existing subscription, billing_cycle_anchor must be either unset, 'now', or 'unchanged"
After that modify the code with 'BillingCycleAnchorNow = now' property. It changed my subscription date to a 30-day future date. (I tried it on 01/04/2024 and it changed the billing date to 01/05/2024). How Can I change the date with my custom date?
This is what I tried;
public int newSPayment()
{
   int issuccess = 0;
   var service = new 
   StripeSubscriptionService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiSecretKey"]);
   DateTime newNextBillingDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5);
   var subscriptionId = "sub_1OwGLfCKifPDqZIAQib3UnBL";
   var cusID = "cus_PjzMQRteo1FhAQ";
   var updateOptions = new StripeSubscriptionUpdateOptions
   {               
      BillingCycleAnchor = newNextBillingDate,                
      BillingCycleAnchorUnchanged = true,
      BillingCycleAnchorNow = true,                
    };
    var updatedSubscription = service.Update(cusID,subscriptionId, updateOptions);
}

Please Help me to solve this problem.

The only way you can do this at Subscription-level is with the trial_end parameter. This will start a trial until that date, then reset the billing period (don't forget to disable prorations with proration_behavior=none).
The official solution to schedule the reset in the future is to use a Susbcription Schedule:

Append a Schedule to your Susbcription:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription
Update the Schedule with a phase to reset the Subscription:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#resetting-anchor

